# What would be the easiest way to parse JSON in C# for a developer having a background in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, swagger

I have a background of Javascript where parsing JSON was dead simple and you had not to worry about types and the stuff at all, now I have to do the same using C#. I need to write a program which will parse swagger definition (like [this one](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/170ce5#)) and later I will have to iterate over it, would you advise the easiest way ahead? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. Do you want to create an object hierarchy and a way to map the JSON to instances of these objects? If so, there are some frameworks such as Newtonsofts Json.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the easiest way is to use Json.NET. It has ability to do the following:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{id: 1, name:'name'}");
```

And then access properties of dynamic object like this:

```
d.id
d.name
```

Here is an exapmle with array:

> http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm